# Remove lines from xml file if contains same words (perl)

Tags: perl

I have a file "frequencies.xml" which contains lines with this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE stationlist PUBLIC "-//xxxxx//DTD stationlist 1.0//EN"   "http://xxxxxxxxx/DTD/xxxxxxxx.dtd">
<frequencies xmlns="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/DTD/">
 <list norm="PAL" frequencies="Custom" audio="bg">
..............................................................
<station name="A" active="1" channel="48.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="B" active="1" channel="55.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="C" active="1" channel="62.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="D" active="1" channel="112.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
..............................................................
<station name="E" active="1" channel="119.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="F" active="0" channel="48.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
..............................................................
<station name="G" active="1" channel="55.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="H" active="0" channel="62.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
..............................................................
  </list>
 </frequencies>
```

I want to remove line considered duplicate if contains same frequencies with other line.

Output results:

```
<station name="A" active="1" channel="48.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="B" active="1" channel="55.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="C" active="1" channel="62.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="D" active="1" channel="112.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
<station name="E" active="1" channel="119.25MHz" norm="PAL"/>
```

I write script to do this:

```
for i in `cat frequencies.xml | sed 's/.*channel="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/; /</ d' |grep MHz`; do
cat frequencies.xml | awk -v i="channel=\"$i" '
    BEGIN       { a=0 }
    $0 ~ i      { if ( a == "1" ) { print i"\" - duplicate" > "/dev/stderr"  ; next ;} ; a=1 } 
            { print $_ }' > frequencies.xml.tmp && \
mv frequencies.xml.tmp frequencies.xml
done
```

How transposing this in perl language?

Thanks

Update: I want to keep XML structure.

My code:

```
open (FH, "+< frequencies.xml") or die "Opening: $!";
my $out = '';
my %seen = ();
foreach my $line ( <FH> ) {
   if ( $line =~ m/<station/ ) {
        my ( $freq ) = ( $line =~ m/channel="([^"]+)"/ );
            $out .= $line unless $seen{$freq}++;
    } else {
        $out .= $line;
    }
}
seek(FH,0,0)                    or die "Seeking: $!";
print FH $out                   or die "Printing: $!";
truncate(FH, tell(FH))          or die "Truncating: $!";
close(FH)                       or die "Closing: $!";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a hash to track what frequencies you've seen, and if you've seen it, don't emit the line:

```
open INPUT, '<', 'frequencies.xml' or die "Can't read file : $!";
my %seen = ();
foreach my $line ( <INPUT> ) {
   my ( $freq ) = ( $line =~ m/channel="([^"]+)"/ );
   print $line unless $seen{$freq};
   $seen{$freq}++;
}
close INPUT;
```

**update** :

If there's other lines to keep, you just need to print them.  The easiest way is likely to just do the test if it's a `<station>` element, and print everything else ... but once you start getting more complex than this, you may want to use one of the true [XML Parsers](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML&mode=all).  So, using Zaid's suggestion:

```
open INPUT, '<', 'frequencies.xml' or die "Can't read file : $!";
my %seen = ();
foreach my $line ( <INPUT> ) {
   if ( $line =~ m/<station/ ) {
      my ( $freq ) = ( $line =~ m/channel="([^"]+)"/ );
      print $line unless $seen{$freq}++;
   } else {
      print $line;
   }
}
close INPUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using a one-line script:

```
perl -ne '($freq) = m/(?i)channel="([^"]+)/; print unless exists $arr{ $freq }; $arr{ $freq } = 1' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open(IN, '<', 'frequencies.xml') or die;
while ($inline = <IN>) {
  $inline =~ /([\d.]+)MHz/;
  $freq = $1;
  push(@out, $inline) unless (grep(/$freq/, @out));
}
print "@out\n";
```

Comment: No need to backslash the dot inside a character class:  `/([\d.]+)MHz/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -pi.tmp -ale '$_="" if $seen{ $F[2] }++' frequencies.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XML::XSH2:

```
use XML::XSH2;
xsh q{
    open so-8853324.xml;
    $ch := hash @channel //station;
    for { keys %$ch } ls xsh:lookup("ch", .)[1];
};
```

I removed the namespace from the data to simplify the code.